# How can I disable ghostscipt rasterization of images and paths?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript, ps, rasterize

I need to convert a PDF to a different ICC color profile. Through different searches and tests, I found out a way to do that:

- First I convert my PDF to a PS file with:

  ```
  .\gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile="test.ps" "test.pdf"
  ```
- Then I convert the PS back to a PDF with the following (this is to generate a valid PDF/X-3 file):

  ```
  .\gswin64c.exe -dPDFX -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
  -sColorConversionStrategy=/UseDeviceIndependentColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK
  -dColorAccuracy=2 -dRenderIntent=0 -sOutputICCProfile="WebCoatedSWOP2006Grade5.icc"
  -dDeviceGrayToK=true -sOutputFile="final.pdf" test_PDFX_def.ps test.ps
  ```

The ICC profile is embedded and all works perfectly. The only problem is that the whole final PDF is rasterized. Here I loose all the paths and other vectorial elements quality I have in the starting file. I need to keep them vectorial because this PDF will have a specific application.

Answer (score 2):

First step **don't** convert to PostScript!!!

Any transparent marking operations will have to be rendered if you do that, because PostScript doesn't support transparency. Other features will  be lost as well, so really, don't do that. The input and output ends of Ghostscript are more or less independent; the pdfwrite device doesn't know whether the input was PDF or PostScript, and doesn't care. So you don't need to convert a PDF file into PostScript before sending it as input.

You can feed the original PDF file into the second command line in place of the PostScript file.

As long as you are producing PDF/X-3 or later then the transparency will be preserved. Make sure you are using an up to date version of Ghostscript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway, I already tried that before, but I had a broken 1KB pdf as result. No warnings or errors at all. I have no more ideas.

Comment: Then I suggest you post the input file somewhere where I can look at it, its not possible to say more without seeing an example. It would be useful to know which version of Ghostscript you are using. You could also open a bug report....

Comment: Ok, I opened a bug report here: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699490. Hope you can help me

Comment: I'll try and look at it tomorrow when I get back to my desk.